# Getting error in tomcat while using NetBeans

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, tomcat, netbeans

When I run a jsp page, Tomcat says

> An attempt was made to authenticate the locked user "admin"
>   org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm authenticate.

I have set user and pass as admin , admin.  I used to have no problems when I used net-beans with bundled tomcate a while ago, and on Linux too.

This time I am using windows 7 64bit (but I don't think its a windows matter)
 its locking every user I give to it

Comment: the user is LockedOut, try debugging the auth realm to see why it is locking out or clear the user from the locked cache

Comment: @BevynQ how? I am a bit new

Comment: how to clear user form locked cache? its locking every user I give to it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Configuration in Tomcat can happen on some levels:

Start with the tomcat installation directory, inspect your **TOMCAT_HOME/conf/server.xml** file. Maybe somewhere is a LockOutRealm. Or look in **TOMCAT_HOME/conf/Catalina/localhost**. Also the war/webapp itself might define a **META-INF/context.xml** file.

Furthermore you could run Tomcat standalone, outside of the IDE.

And NetBeans has settings too.

Do you really run your application as user `admin`? I would not do that for a production environment.